# Getting negative information gain with Laplace smoothing

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, entropy, information-gain

Is it possible to get negative information gain if Laplace smoothing is used too?

We know:

```
IG = H(Y) - H(Y|X)
```

Here, H is the entropy function and IG is the information gain.

Also:

> H(Y) = -Σ<sub>y</sub>P(Y=y).log<sub>2</sub>(P(Y=y))
>
> H(Y|X) = Σ<sub>x</sub>P(X=x).H(Y|X=x)
>
> H(Y|X=x) = -Σ<sub>y</sub>P(Y=y|X=x).log<sub>2</sub>(P(Y=y|X=x))

For example, suppose P(Y=y|X=x) = n<sub>y|x</sub>/n<sub>x</sub>. But it is possible that n<sub>x</sub> = 0 and n<sub>y|x</sub> = 0. So, I do laplace smoothing and define P(Y=y|X=x) = (n<sub>y|x</sub>+1)/(n<sub>x</sub>+|X|). Here, |X| denote the number of possible values that X can take(number of splits possible if X is chosen as the attribute). Is it possible that due to laplace smoothing, I get negative information gain?

Comment: Is this a Python coding question?

Comment: No, not really!

Comment: I found the answer! If Laplace smoothing done naively, then it can lead to a negative IG, otherwise not.